# How to declare a license usage in android app

Tags: license-notice

I'm building an app and willing to post it on play store.

1. As common when build the app specially for the beginners like me, I used to ask questions at the web specially Stack Overflow about how to implement some methods, listeners,etc.. (not libraries) and got replies from different users. Now I don't now if my android app contains those techniques of implementing different methods and classes which I do not know whether it belongs to someone or not. From other side I also share some of my techniques to others when I got issues solved by myself.
2. I'm using openCSV library in my app, do I need to declare it in the license? and how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you were instructed by others on **how** to write the code in your app, the app code itself is still an original work by **you** and no license is necessary.  Even if they offered you 'snippets' the functions still originated by your hand.  If they have **not** notified you of their own license on code they shared, then any assistance given to you is covered under Stack Exchange's license, which is printed and linked at the bottom of this page.

It basically says what I just stated... 
*"All the content contributed to Stack Overflow or other Stack Exchange sites is cc-wiki (aka cc-by-sa) licensed, intended to be shared and remixed. We even provide all our data as a convenient data dump, seeded by us..."*

**There is a license that is required to be included when using the openCSV library**...it is listed in their repository: http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/license.html

You did not mention what language you are coding in, but pay attention to that as well... if your IDE is not including licensing for you, your language of choice could possibly have its own and/or others' licenses due to included libraries, frameworks, etc...

Congrats on your published app!  :-)

-shel.

Comment: Iam doing android programming. Thanks a lot for the feedback. The last statement is not clear to me